# the difference between reference and object in java

Tags: java, object, reference

In class Main we create a reference variable a from class A ,we all know that 
we not able to use the reference  a until we assign it an object ( A a = new A (); ) because a currently does not point to any object 
so we must not use property and methods of A class

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {             
      A a = null;      
         a.x=5 ;       // fine code in compile time    
         a.y=10 ;     // fine code in compile time     
         a.show();   // fine code in compile time       

    } 
}
 class A {       
     int x ;     
     int y ;      
     public void show (){      
         System.out.println("show method");
     }     
 }
```

a is reference variable not object ,so the reference a not allocated in memory so it must not see the variable x ,y and the method show in A class in compile time my question here why reference a see x ,y and show method in the compile time although the reference a not allocated in memory ?

Comment: The difference between soft and warm

Comment: `static` methods can be accessed by instance variables, and this is a compile-time feature, not a runtime issue, so the NPE doesn't come into play. `a.show()` is the same as `A.show()`, but you should prefer the latter.

Comment: To elaborate a bit: `a.show()` is _exactly_ equivalent to `A.show()` in your example. It's weird, but that's Java.

Comment: thanks , but why the reference a access x ,y and the show method in compile time?

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry.

Comment: a is reference variable  not object ,so the reference a not allocated in memory so must not see the variable x ,y and the method show in A class  in compile time my question here why reference a see x ,y and show method in the compile time although the reference a not allocated in memory  ? i hope to show my problem in clearly

Answer (score -3):

the show() method gives you information about the refference itself( about a). Accesing a member of the object through "a" when "a" is not assigned to any object is illegal. show() will only display information regarding the "a" variable.
Your show() method being static will run as thanks to your class. It is not bound to your variable